# Create Jenkins JOB analyzing Git Repository with SonarQube

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube

I want to create in Jenkins a JOB that analyze with sonar a Git repository.

Is that possible without a Maven Build? because I already have a maven JOB that build the projet and I just want to link the two JOBS in one Pipeline.

Thank you for your help.
Mohamed Reda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to not trigger another Maven Job, you can use https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner.

However, I highly recommends to integrate SonarQube analysis in you Maven job in order to have coverage and unit tests.

You'll be able to find the information here : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner